# How to do a batch update for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

```
UPDATE wlog 
  SET g_log = ( SELECT glog_id 
                FROM glog_wlog 
                WHERE w_id=wlog.id limit 5) 
WHERE g_log is NULL;
```

My old DB consisted of mapping table `"glog_wlog"`. Which now I need to change the way it refers. Above code works fine. But the limit 5 really does not do anything. I have more than 1 million recodes in the tables. I do not want to convert them all in one go. So How to break it into any given number?

Comment: Seems that subquery returns 1 row because in other case you will get an error.

Comment: Use `UPDATE ... FROM`; see `UPDATE` in the manual. There's no LIMIT clause, but you can use a `WHERE` clause to filter by ranges of IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CTE to limit the records you're viewing to do this sort of subset.

eg:

```
with wlog_targets as (
    select id from wlog
    where g_log is null
    limit 5)
update wlog
set
    g_log = g.glog_id
from wlog_targets w
inner join glog_wlog g
    on w.id = g.w_id
where 
    wlog.id = w.id;
```

This approach uses the wlog_targets CTE to extract a small subset of wlog records to process.

This does have an issue in if the 5 records chosen don't have an entry in glog_wlog then nothing gets updated.  Also, the CTE isn't sorted, so it might be any 5 records returned.